# How to disable Membership Providers completely in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Our MVC 4 project doesn't need any membership providers. I am getting this strange error sometimes, but not always:

```
Default Membership Provider could not be found
```

Is there a way to disable all membership providers? I have no membership provider in the web.config

Comment: Remove them from the web.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Web.config, under , add

```
 <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

This should clean any existing membership providers.